# Exporting multiple datagridviews to different tabs of excelsheet

Tags: excel, datagridview, checkedlistbox, vba

I'm a newbie to visual studio.

I want to export different datagridviews from multiple forms to an excel workbook as different sheets on the same workbook based on whether it is checked in checkedlist box.

Basically I am doing a daily checklist for our school on location basis where the user can export checklist floor wise on the corresponding form of each floor, but also can export a multiple sheet workbook containing diff floors as per its checked in checklistbox, any help please? I am stuck at checkedlistbox. currently i am doing as below: but gives me an exception at the second sheet.

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)

Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

Dim sheetnumber As Integer = 1

If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) = True Then

    worksheet = workbook.Sheets(sheetnumber)

    sheetnumber = sheetnumber + 1

    worksheet.Name = "Anim_Check List_"

    Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1

    Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To Form7.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        For j As Integer = 0 To Form7.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

            If cellRowIndex = 1 Then

                worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = Form7.DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText

            Else
                worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = Form7.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()

            End If

            cellColumnIndex += 1

        Next

        cellColumnIndex = 1

        cellRowIndex += 1

    Next

End If

If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) = True Then

    workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetnumber)

    excel.Worksheets(sheetnumber).activate

    sheetnumber = sheetnumber + 1

    worksheet.Name = "Edits 1-5_"

    Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1

    Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To Form8.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        For j As Integer = 0 To Form8.DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

            If cellRowIndex = 1 Then

                worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = Form8.DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText

            Else

                worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = Form8.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()

            End If

            cellColumnIndex += 1

        Next

        cellColumnIndex = 1

        cellRowIndex += 1

    Next

End If

Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()

saveDialog.FileName = workbook.Name

saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"

saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1


If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)

    MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do. From what I can decipher, there appears to be three (3) different `WindowsForm`s open. The main active form has a `Button` and a `CheckedListBox`. The two other forms (Form7, Form8) each have a `DataGridView` with some data.

I assume that the `CheckListBox` allows the user to select which form to use when exporting to Excel. Example, if the user checks the first option, then clicks the button, then the `DataGridView` on `Form7` will be exported to the Excel workbook. If the second option is checked then `Form8`’s `DataGridView` will be exported to the same workbook.

I hope I have this correct. To help, I would recommend you break the problem down into smaller pieces. Example, looking at the code in both “if” statements that check for a checked state in the checked list box… it is clear they are doing the same thing. The only difference is the `DataGridView` and the name of the worksheet.

It looks like a method, that took a workbook to add the sheet to, a `DataGridView` to export and finally a string for the worksheet name… might come in handy.

```
Private Sub AddGridToWorkbook(workbook As Workbook, dgv As DataGridView, sheetName As String)
```

This method would add a new worksheet to the given workbook using the given `sheetName` as the name for the new worksheet. Lastly the method would loop through the given `DataGridView` and export the values to the new worksheet.

The current posted code is trying to print the header row inside the loop through the grids rows. This will miss the first row of data. The header row for the new excel worksheet needs to be exported separately and outside the loop through the grids rows.

Lastly, I am curious what `Form7` and `Form8` are… If these are `WindowsForm` “Classes”… then the statement:…

```
worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = Form7.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
```

This will not work as you expect… `Form7` is a “Class” and you are using it like an instantiated object.

In my example below, I have two `WindowsForm`s “Classes” called “Form7” and “Form8”. When the main form loads, I instantiate and show these two forms. Example: create the global variable forms.

```
Dim form7 As Form7 = New Form7()
Dim form8 As Form8 = New Form8()
```

Then show the forms on load.

```
form7.Show()
form8.Show()
```

Now the previous line of code will work using the instantiated “Form7” object named `form7`.

```
worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = form7.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
```

Revised code to export the grids

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    excel.Visible = True
    Dim workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()

    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) = True Then
        AddGridToWorkbook(workbook, form7.DataGridView1, "Anim_Check List_")
    End If

    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) = True Then
        AddGridToWorkbook(workbook, form8.DataGridView1, "Edits 1-5_")
    End If

    Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveDialog.FileName = workbook.Name
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1

    If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
        MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddGridToWorkbook(workbook As Workbook, dgv As DataGridView, sheetName As String)
    Try
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add()
        worksheet.Name = sheetName
        AddHeaderRow(worksheet, dgv)
        For row As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            For col As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
                If dgv.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    worksheet.Cells(row + 2, col + 1) = dgv.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value.ToString()
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Ex: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddHeaderRow(worksheet As Worksheet, dgv As DataGridView)
    For col As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
        worksheet.Cells(1, col + 1) = dgv.Columns(col).HeaderText
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank u,works like charm adding sheets, but unfortunately not populating the cells in exported sheet. i am missing something.watever u guessed on wat i am trying to acheive is correct,apart,this code is in Form6, and in Form7 & 8 i already have the datagrid populated and edited by user which i wanted to export from Form6 when i check respective checklist and then click button.I get sheets with name but no content in it.wer wud you advise to instantiate and show the forms Dim form7 As Form7 = New Form7()
Dim form8 As Form8 = New Form8() Then show the forms on load.
form7.Show()
form8.Show()

Comment: As you stated in your comment:… _”code is in Form6, and in Form7 & 8 i already have the datagrid populated and edited by user”_  … if form 7 and 8 are already open and displayed… how/where are you instantiating those forms? Can you show the code where you are creating an instance of those forms (form7 and form8)? Again the line of code: `Form7.DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText`…looks odd. It looks like “Form7” is a “Class”, however I could be wrong because I do not see how it is defined/instantiated.